# Открытие полноразмерного изображения по нажатию в Ionic-приложении

Tags: angularjs, ionic, ionicframework

Пишу приложение на ionic. Нужно добавить возможность просмотреть изображение в полном размере при нажатии на него. Раньше на сайтах для таких целей всегда подключал jquery fancybox, но в этот раз при всём желании так и не смог подключить данную библиотеку к angularJs. Возможно в angular или ionic есть собственные библиотеки для данных целей? Кто может подсказать?